# Minor tweak autopair emacs

Tags: emacs, brackets

Does anyone know how to change autopair.el in such a way that, when you have a region, pressing `(` results in the point being before the ( instead of within the brackets?

It has been annoying me for a long time, because whenever I have a region selected and I want to insert brackets, I do not want point to be within brackets.

Standard behavior      SELECTED REGION TEXT ->  ([point] TEXT )

Preferable behavior    SELECTED REGION TEXT ->  [point]](TEXT)

Comment: This seems tricky. Notice that autopair sets the point to a different position depending on the start and end of the current active region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dirty version: change `1+` to `1-` in line 952 of `autopair.el`. I currently don't see a way to do that kind of modification cleanly. I have filed an [issue](https://github.com/capitaomorte/autopair/issues/14) to make this customization easier.

Comment: I made a small function that does "left-char" after auto-pair, but it runs into the same problem as this. I think you didn't try this, because it actually brings you one character back too far.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the already extra effort put into this, though.

Comment: @Dualinity I also didn't try it because `autopair` will put point at different places depending on wrapping with a closing or opening brace.

Comment: Also, could region-beginning have a higher position value than region-end? If that's the case I predict more trouble.

Comment: pmr Pointed out where the issue is, gave a half solution (1- actually weirdly does -2), really ugly adding `(right-char 1)` solves it, as in the below answer. Thanks for filing a request.

Answer (score 0):

Starting at line 952 as pmr pointed out:

```
(goto-char (1+ (car region-before))))
```

Change to:

```
(goto-char (1- (car region-before)))
(right-char 1))
```